# Accessing Uncaught Promise Rejection Error Stack

Tags: javascript, error-handling, stack-trace, es6-promise

Is is possible to access the stack trace with the "unhandledrejection" promise event?

```js
self.addEventListener("error", function(event) {
 console.log(event.error.stack)
 event.preventDefault()
}) //works

self.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function(event) {
 console.log(event.error.stack)
 event.preventDefault()
}) //fails

Promise.reject()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an Error object as the rejection reason then you'll have access to the stack.

```
self.addEventListener("error", function(event) {
  console.log(event.error.stack)
  event.preventDefault()
}) //works

self.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function(event) {
  console.log(event.stack)
  event.preventDefault()
}) //works

Promise.reject(
  new Error('rejected') // here's the magic
)
```